# Bialetti stove top condition

Tags: espresso, cleaning

Thinking of buying my partner a new Bialetti, would you say the condition of the current one warrants replacing? (see pic) or is that normal wear and tear?

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 2):

Is this the inside of the moka pot? If so, toss it and buy a new one **immediately**. What you can see is probably old, burnt and rancid coffee. In the worst case there might even be some rust there but I can't really tell from this picture. This looks like it hasn't been cleaned properly ever. Make sure to rinse your new moka pot really well after each use and also clean it with dish soap or other cleaning agents regularly.

Comment: Won't soap attack the aluminium coating? I always clean mine immediately after use with my fingers under running water. Leaving no residue whatsoever.